# Setting field values generic SObject

Tags: apex, sobject, dynamic-apex

Is there a way to instantiate an SObject?

I have done the following:

```
Id objId = 'a0Ci000000vd7xA';            
String objName = ((Id)objId).getSobjectType().getDescribe().getName();

Type t = Type.forName(objName); //object name
Sobject  myObj =  (Sobject)t.newInstance();

myObj.emp_name__c = 'test';
```

> Field expression not allowed for generic SObject

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need to go through the complicated method you went through to get the new record. The following works just as well:

```
Id objId = 'a0Ci000000vd7xA';
SObject record = objId.getSObjectType().newSObject(objId);
```

This approach also has the advantage that it also works even if someone does something silly like creating a class called "Account" and you try to instantiate an Account record.

If you want to use the static methods, you have to first cast to a concrete type:

```
CustomObject__c record = (CustomObject__c)objId.getSObjectType().newSObject(objId);
```

However, if you want to use the object generically, you use the get/put SObject methods:

```
record.put('Name','New Name Value');
```

Comment: I will be dealing with sObject meaning that I cann't have hard code any object name, if i have something like this then getting the same error that 

i have posted above, so here is what i'm trying to do instead of hard-coding i'm getting the value by running soql in results var and assigning to it `record.put('Name', results.name);`

Comment: @NickKahn You can use the get method to get a field's value dynamically as well.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to put values into fields, you can use the generic `put` methods:

```
SObject record = Id.valueOf('a0Ci000000vd7xA').getSObjectType.newSObject();
record.put('emp_name__c', 'test');
```

Or you can also use a `SObjectField`:

```
record.put(SomeObject__c.SomeField__c, 'Some Value');
```

Comment: Would be worth getting the Id and then passing it to the newSObject() call.